# How to set a global vector within multiple files and VS projects in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's a minimal reproducible example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm trying to set up a standard vector that will contain a list of all the possible operations my program can use. These operations are defined using my class `Option`, which is defined in my `classes.cpp` file. I want it to be set initially in my `main.cpp` file, but it should be usable in my `setter.cpp` file, in which I fill the vector.

Here is my code:

Main.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "classes.h"

extern std::vector<Option*> OPTIONS;
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "classes.h"
#include "setter.h"

std::vector<Option*> OPTIONS = {};

int main()
{
    initOptions(); //function from setter.cpp
    
    OPTIONS[0]->pFunc(); // EXCEPTION at 0xCCCCCCCC in Main.exe: 0xC0000005: Acccess infraction when executing 0xCCCCCCCC.

    return 0;
}
```

setter.h

```
#pragma once

void foo();
void initOptions();
```

setter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Main.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world :)" << std::endl;
}

void initOptions()
{
    OPTIONS = {
        &Option("Test String", &foo)
    };
}
```

classes.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

struct Option
{
    std::string name;
    void (*pFunc)();
    Option(std::string n, void (*pF)()) : name(n), pFunc(pF) {};
};
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, all Main and setter files are in the same project, but classes.h is in another one (I know maybe this is not the most efficient way of doing things, but this is one of my first "interesting" projects and I'm trying to experiment a bit).

It compiles just fine, but when I execute it throw the exception: `EXCEPTION at 0xCCCCCCCC in Main.exe: 0xC0000005: Acccess infraction when executing 0xCCCCCCCC.`. Using the inspection tool from VS I can see that the `OPTIONS` vector has one element, but it is empty (string is `""` and function pointer is `0x00000000`). Am I declaring the global vector wrong? Did I not link projects correctly? Thanks in advance!

P.D: I tried to minimize and translate my code (not native speaker), so if there is incorrect spelling it's probably my translation and not the actual code :P

Comment: Only use the brackets initializers at the point of definition, and nowhere else.  You should use push_back() to insert elements in your vector, or else declare OPTIONS as const (I think you should), and use the bracket initializers at the point of declaration.

Comment: Also check your setter.cpp file, with what you are showing, you are trying get the address of a temporary object.

Comment: `0xCCCCCCCC` means uninitialized stack memory.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I changed the vector to store Option instances, not pointers, and it does work! I don't know which way is better, pointer or instance, but just to know: how could I keep the instance of the object alive to prevent it from causing the exception?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy thanks for the upgrade! It does seem logic to keep it as a const vector. However, I didn't really understand how could I do it: should I define the vector in the setter.cpp file, and change the extern declaration to its header file? Kinda confused, sorry for the newbie question :/

Comment: @lambda You can declare a static option object like `static Option myOption("Test String", &foo);` then use `&myOption` if that's what you want

Comment: @lambda define the const vector and its contents in the cpp and declare as extern in the header file.  One would normally expect the definition this vector with all commands handled by the app to be in the same cpp as main().

Comment: @lambda  There is thet one argument that could go against declaring the commands non-const.  That is if you plan to later add functionnality to your app as optional dynamically linked libraries.  Your call.

Comment: @lambda  And this also is wrong, and will cause crashes: `{  &Option("Test String", &foo) }` .  The address of a variable created on the stack is not only very short-lived, but totally unusable.  Do not place pointers to Option objects in OPTIONS, but the objects themselves.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Now the vector is const, stores the objects themselves and is defined in the setter.cpp file, and can be used in my Main.cpp file. For the moment I'll keep it like this, I'm glad I understood how to make something like this, even if it's not the most optimal solution in this situation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @lambda  You're welcome!